# Should My Swagger doc (aka Open API) define 500 response codes?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-2.0, openapi, autorest

If I'm going to use a client generator like AutoRest, do I want that generated client to anticipate 500 errors?

Or, am I expected to wrap the client requests in try/catch?

Is this just a stylistic decision I need to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) (free, open source), the API client usually returns an Exception (e.g. ApiException) for 4xx or 5xx HTTP response as it indicates something wrong happened (e.g. deleting an object that never exists in the database) and usually the ApiException object contains all the information about the errors returned by the server.

Comment: after gaining an understanding of how various client generators work, probably the correct answer is "it depends".. but I think your answer is probably indicative of the general intended approach